# What exactly TDD stands for?

Tags: tdd, agile

What exactly TDD stands for?

I have seen two versions :

1. Test Driven Design
2. Test Driven Development

So, which one is correct and why?

Comment: Of course it can be both but `Test Driven Development` was first :)

Comment: @marc_s That doesn't help at all.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/tdd/info  Doesn't exactly answer it, but really, both are correct.

Comment: @Carl Great. I never read tag descriptions before. Thanks. It really made me wonder what is the correct, since there are many pages related to TDD, but some are using one name, and others other.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are broadly the same, but different in actual meaning.

Test driven development means that you write tests and then your classes. (yes, in that order.)

The design part means that you have better designed classes if you write your tests first. You won't write quick and dirty if you know that your code will go trough some tests. Thus, test driven development results in test driven design.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 1):

I think it rather means Test Driven Development as it is a way to write Software (i.e. develop) by first writing some tests and then the productive code to satisfy all requirements defined by these tests.